# Unable to override style switchStyle and NumberPicker in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, styles

I cannot override the android:switchStyle. Here's what i've done :

In folder values-v14, i have two files :

themes.xml :

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:switchStyle">@style/SwitchAppTheme</item>
</style>
```

styles.xml :

```
<style name="SwitchAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.Switch">
  <item name="android:track">@drawable/switch_track_holo_light</item>
  <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/switch_inner_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

I've got the following errors :

> res/values-v14/styles.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item:
>   No resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Holo.Light.CompoundButton.Switch'.
>
> res/values-v14/themes.xml:5: error: Error: No resource found that
>   matches the given name: attr 'android:switchStyle'.

I've got the same problem with NumberPicker:

themes.xml :

```
<item name="android:numberPickerUpButtonStyle">@style/NumberPickerButtonUpAppTheme</item>
<item name="android:numberPickerDownButtonStyle">@style/NumberPickerButtonDownAppTheme</item>
<item name="android:numberPickerStyle">@style/NumberPickerAppTheme</item>
```

styles.xml :

```
<style name="NumberPickerButtonUpAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ImageButton.NumberPickerUpButton">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/numberpicker_up_btn_holo_light</item>
</style>

<style name="NumberPickerButtonDownAppTheme" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ImageButton.NumberPickerDownButton">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/numberpicker_down_btn_holo_light</item>
</style>
```

I have the following errors :

> /res/values-v11/themes.xml:26: error: Error: No resource found that
>   matches the given name: attr 'android:numberPickerStyle'.
>
> /res/values-v11/themes.xml:25: error: Error: No resource found that
>   matches the given name: attr 'android:numberPickerDownButtonStyle'.
>
> /res/values-v11/themes.xml:25: error: Error: No resource found that
>   matches the given name: attr 'android:numberPickerUpButtonStyle'.

My project use SDK 16, so it should be available... Same error in eclipse and IntelliJ.

How to extend these styles ? I can extend many others (buttonStyle, buttonStyleToggle, seekBarStyle...) in the same way...

Comment: Ran into the same exact issue. Looks like it was reported as a Google bug as well. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=36636

Comment: Yes, i have created the bug because i'm quite sure i didn't make any mistake, but i also created this post in case of someone has any idea...

Comment: You can check the public attributes by looking at android.R.attr on the docs.

Comment: You are right, they are not in R.attr... damned!

Answer (score 4):

Styles for the Switch widget are not public.

You can use [android-switch-backport](https://github.com/BoD/android-switch-backport) or [SwitchCompatLibrary](https://github.com/ankri/SwitchCompatLibrary).
They also work with [Android Holo Colors](http://android-holo-colors.com/)

There is also an alternative for the Number Picker: [Better Pickers](https://github.com/derekbrameyer/android-betterpickers)

I hope I'm helpful.

Comment: Thanks I know that, i am the author of Holo Colors ;) I hope Google will do something....

Comment: Good work with Holo Colors :)

Not much we can do except vote/star the issue.