# Illegal resource reference: @*android resources are private and not always present

Tags: android, resources, styles, timepicker, numberpicker

```
<style name="mystyle" parent="@*android:style/Widget.Holo.NumberPicker">
</style>
```

when i use it in my style,system report the error " Illegal resource reference: @*android resources are private and not always present",what is the problem

Comment: `They are private and not always present`: Read that loud and you might understand that there is no guarantee that these resources are always there and accessible.

Comment: have other way to extend Widget.Holo.NumberPicker?

Comment: Maybe by removing the `*`? Also for with API versions do you develop?

Comment: if i remove the *,i get "error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name '@android:style/Widget.NumberPicker'"

Comment: Again: What API version do you have defined in your manifest?

Comment: <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

Answer (score 0):

Simply said: This is not possible. There is no public style for the number picker. You could have tried it with a simple search for "style numberpicker" to find this SO question/answer: [Unable to override style switchStyle and NumberPicker in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12201309/unable-to-override-style-switchstyle-and-numberpicker-in-android)